# Making a View's width based on screen width

Tags: android, android-layout, width, android-view

I am trying to let a View's width be based on the width of the screen. Depending on a value from 0 to 100, the width will be that percentage of the screen width. Here is how I am getting the screen width in DP:

```
Display display = ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
float density  = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float screenWidthDP = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
```

This returns 360dp for my device which is correct. I then use this to set the width of my view, where timeCountNewRange() returns a value from 0 - 100:

```
int timeCountNewRange = getNewRangeTimeCount(timeCount, min, max);
int widthDP = (int) (((double)timeCountNewRange / 100.0) * screenWidthDP);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(widthDP, 15);
params.setMargins(5, 0, 0, 0);
appHolder.timeBar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

For some reason, when the "timeCountNewRange" value is 100 it is only about 60% of the screen width, and everything else is shorter as well. If replace

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(widthDP, 15);
```

with

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(360, 15);
```

the view is still only around 60% of the screen width. This error differs from device to device based on screen size. How do I properly set the width to be based upon the screen width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout params will be set in pixels if set programmatically. You will have to convert the dp to pixels again and set the width